# Displaying a multiple object arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am curious as to how would I show a multiple object arraylist in Java. The array list contains both string and int.

This is the class of which I am making a arraylist of.

```
public class Movie
{

    public int rating;
    public String title, directorName, actorOne, actorTwo, actorThree;


    public Movie(String Title, String Director, String ActorOne, String ActorTwo, String ActorThree, int Rating)
    {
        title = Title;
        directorName = Director;
        actorOne = ActorOne;
        actorTwo = ActorTwo;
        actorThree = ActorThree;
        rating =  Rating;
    }


    public void setTitle(String Title)
    {

        title = Title;

    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

        public void setDirector(String Director)
    {

        directorName = Director;

    }

    public String getDirector()
    {
        return directorName;
    }

     public void setActorOne(String ActorOne)
    {

        actorOne = ActorOne;

    }

    public String getActorOne()
    {
        return actorOne;
    }

        public void setActorTw0(String ActorTwo)
    {

        actorTwo = ActorTwo;

    }

    public String getActorTwo()
    {
        return actorTwo;
    }

        public void setActorThree(String ActorThree)
    {

        actorThree = ActorThree;

    }

    public String getActorThree()
    {
        return actorThree;
    }
}
```

This is my main class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Database
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean start;
    ArrayList<Movie> movie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    String title, director, actOne, actTwo, actThree;
    int rating;
    public Database()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.display();
    }
    public void display()                   
    {
        while (start = true)            
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Movie Database");
            System.out.println
            (
                    "Select an option \n" +
                    "1 Find Movie \n" +
                    "2 Add Movie \n" +
                    "3 Delete Movie \n" +
                    "4 Display Favourtite Movies \n" +
                    "5 Exit Database \n" 

            );
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            switch(choice)                      
                {
                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.addMovie();
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        this.exit();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void exit()                             
    {
        System.out.println("Exiting");
        start = false;
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void addMovie()
    {        
       System.out.println("Insert Movie Name: ");
       title = input.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Insert Director Name: ");
       director = input.nextLine();     

        System.out.println("Insert Actor One Name: ");
         actOne = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Actor Two Name: ");
        actTwo = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Actor Three Name: ");
        actThree = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insert Movie Rating: ");
        rating = input.nextInt();


         movie.add(new Movie(title, director, actOne, actTwo, actThree, rating));

    }



}
```

I just wish to see if I my program is actually adding to array list.
Thank you

Comment: override toString and print the list...

Comment: As the declaration says `ArrayList<Movie>`, the list only contains `Movie`, not `String` and `int`.

Comment: Alright, so what did you try to do to achieve that? And what is the problem with it?

Comment: "I just wish to see if I my program is actually adding to array list" - You could simply add a breakpoint at the end of your `addMovie()` method and check the contents of `movie` using your IDE's debug tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find helpful overriding toString method in the movie class and then printing the arrayList everytime you do something with it...

```
System.out.println("actual state of the list: "+movie);
```

and override the toString method in the movie class... somthing descripting the object... like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Movie [rating=" + rating + ", title=" + title + ", directorName=" + directorName + ", actorOne="
            + actorOne + ", actorTwo=" + actorTwo + ", actorThree=" + actorThree + "]";
}
```